# PHP Cookie, for show/dont show

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to add a simple security script to my page. 
"if cookie exists show page
else don't show"

no cookie creation script so manual addition will be needed so only people that make it manually can view the page (I know you can show the code and edit it to easily view it but its links to internal pages. so only people on the Work internet can see them anyway.) also the Work computers have javascript disabled. so will have to be php.

To clarify its access control that meets the following restrictions

1. can not be accessed remotely: so not a normal login
2. if a different user uses the same computer it will not work: so not address filtering
3. must be setup by an "administrator" so the number of users that have access can be managed.
4. can not be JavaScript. as its disabled on the users devices.

Comment: you will likely use PHP sessions to accomplish this... try reading about sessions first then come back here if you any problems with sessions.

Comment: I see, but I think sessions will not solve it. as we have 5 or 6 users that will need this setup and only them. so it will have to have something that will be active for only those devices/users. but will remain open between sessions. almost like a login controlled by a file within the users account rather than a login. so it cant be accessed by logging in remotely.

Comment: to clarify its access ctrl that meets the following restrictions
1) can not be accessed remotely: so not a normal login
2) if a different user uses the same computer it will not work: so not address filtering
3) must be setup by an "administrator" so the number of users that have access can be managed.
4) can not be JavaScript. as its disabled on the users devices.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have Devised a slightly different solution. do a cookie that has a random but specific value and do a "read Cookie, set variable if variable is not XXX then forward to www.google.co.uk" with no "else" so if it is the page loads without question.